# How and where is syscall.Syscall() defined for Windows-specific system calls in Golang's syscall package?

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to understand some of the low-level details of Golangs syscall package. In particular, I'm interested in Windows-specific system calls (see the example below).

I can find the definition of `syscall.Syscall()` for UNIX-based systems:

- https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go?s=496:562#L18
- https://golang.org/src/syscall/asm_unix_amd64.s

However, I cannot find any such definition for Windows-based systems, like an `asm_windows_amd64.s`.

In particular, `asm_unix_amd64.s` has the following build directive, so its `·Syscall(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-56` definition cannot be the one also called for Windows system calls:

```
 1// +build netbsd freebsd openbsd dragonfly
```

Where is `syscall.Syscall()` defined for Windows-based systems?

**Example:**
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#example-LoadLibrary

```
h, err := windows.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
if err != nil {
    abort("LoadLibrary", err)
}
defer windows.FreeLibrary(h)
proc, err := windows.GetProcAddress(h, "GetVersion")
if err != nil {
    abort("GetProcAddress", err)
}
r, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(proc), 0, 0, 0, 0)
major := byte(r)
minor := uint8(r >> 8)
build := uint16(r >> 16)
print("windows version ", major, ".", minor, " (Build ", build, ")\n")
```

Comment: Because Windows *renumbers* the system calls every hour or so (ok, maybe every month or so), nobody in his right mind actually uses them directly. The invocations always go through some DLL that uses unpublished Microsoft secrets to map from names to system-call numbers. Go appears to do the same thing, and further, generates code at build-time to make the calls to the DLLs, using https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/mkwinsyscall/mkwinsyscall.go

Comment: @torek - can you find the definition of `syscall.Syscall()` that gets called in the above example: `r, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(proc), 0, 0, 0, 0)`? Also, here I'm not using a system call number, but instead the DLL address of the function: `windows.GetProcAddress(h, "GetVersion")`

Comment: ... I think. Windows is a mystery; I recommend not using it myself, and don't have it. AHA: no, it's in `runtime/syscall_windows.go`.

Comment: https://golang.org/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go?h#L179

Comment: Linkname pragma exports function with given name

Comment: @LaevusDexter - can you provide some details on how the function is exported?

Comment: @Shuzheng first word after linkname is variable on the current space, second one is its global name

Comment: After putting it in global space, you can import it from global space the same way, assigning on local space variable/function without body

Comment: All functions and variables from std packages are constantly exported, so you can import them using linkname

Comment: @LaevusDexter - don't you mean that the first word after linkname is a value, not variable? Furhermore, `//go:linkname syscall_Syscall syscall.Syscall`, here we export the `syscall_Syscall` function as `syscall.Syscall`. Does that make `syscall.Syscall` part of the `syscall` package? Or could you refer to `syscall.Syscall` without importing the `syscall` package? If `syscall.Syscall` becomes part of the `syscall` package, isn't it bad practice to have the `runtime` package add functions to another package?

Comment: Linkname can be used apart from variable declaration. So first word is exactly the variable/function in local space. In case of std packages, it becomes part of destination package as is. In case of user-usage it require to be imported manually, by applying linkname on both(except std one) sides.

Comment: Code has been rewritten from C, so this trick is a one of methods to avoid copy-paste which wasn't a problem in C. As reflect uses a lot of types/functions from runtime, syscall goes same way.

Comment: It's perhaps misleading that user-mode subsystem calls are getting called "system calls". These are not calls into the NT executive. System calls into the kernel are exported by ntdll.dll and win32u.dll, but using them directly is rarely supported. For example, the `NtCreateUserProcess` system call on its own will usually create a dysfunctional process. The proper call is WINAPI `CreateProcessW`, exported by kernel32.dll. It calls `NtCreateUserProcess`, but it also does a lot in user mode, including setting up the connection to the session server, csrss.exe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have or use Windows, but some grep work with the source finds this:

- `syscall.Syscall`, `syscall.Syscall6`, and so on are defined in [`runtime/syscall_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go).  For instance, starting at line 179 (currently):

  ```
  //go:linkname syscall_Syscall syscall.Syscall
  //go:nosplit
  func syscall_Syscall(fn, nargs, a1, a2, a3 uintptr) (r1, r2, err uintptr) {
      lockOSThread()
      defer unlockOSThread()
      c := &getg().m.syscall
      c.fn = fn
      c.n = nargs
      c.args = uintptr(noescape(unsafe.Pointer(&a1)))
      cgocall(asmstdcallAddr, unsafe.Pointer(c))
      return c.r1, c.r2, c.err
  ```

  }

  The `go:linkname` is the magic that makes this function  be named `syscall.Syscall`, even though it's named `runtime.syscall_Syscall` here.
- These use DLLs loaded earlier to figure out how to really make the system calls.  (This is what `c.fn` is about.)  To call into the DLLs, the Go runtime must lock the thread (see the first two calls) and use `cgocall` to invoke the DLL.  Furthermore, special trickery is required to pass the parameters using the structure obtained by `getc().m.syscall`.
- Startup loading appears to happen via [`runtime/os_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/os_windows.go).  Note that `_GetProcAddress` (and other functions) are filled-in by the Windows loader, which allows bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks. Don't you mean it's named `runtime.syscall_Syscall`? It's an odd decision that Unix syscalls are defined in `syscall` package, while those for Windows are defined in `runtime` - I had no idea to look there. How are these functions linked? Is it like static linking or dynamic linking?

Comment: Oops, right, it would be `runtime.syscall_Syscall` but for the linkname trick. Will fix.

Comment: do you also know how the linking happens? The `//go:linkname` doesn't really refers to "binary linking" does it? It's only creating an alias at runtime, right?

Comment: As for the linkage, I have not investigated how the Go compiler and linker work, but they're private to the Go build system.